# Contacts sync via CardDav misses some

Tags: iphone, contacts, gmail, carddav

I recently set up a CardDav account on my iPhone 4S which is running iOS 6.01. It synced with my GMail account just fine, however, the Contacts app only shows those that are within the My Contacts group. I have a handful of other groups that I've created to organize my contacts, so not all of them are shown under My Contacts (what they call a contact group seems to be just a label).

My question is, how can I view/use **all** my GMail contacts on my iPhone, regardless of the GMail group they are in? Or is that something Google doesn't support yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is a default behaviour of Google Mail.
On Android there is a fairly hidden way to select more groups but not on iOS or other normal cardDAV clients.

You may find fruux an alternative that works fine for me in this case.
If there is a single addressbook at fruux with a default name like “contacts”, iOS will attempt to interpret vcf-Groups as contact groups. E. g. eM Client will create contact groups for each new assigned category simultanously.